# Replacing text with Jquery works with class but not id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So for the view page I've tried `<div id= <%= dom_id(Video.find(x.id)) %>> <%= x.get_upvotes.size %> </div>`

For the upvote.js.erb page I've tried `Rails.$('#<%=dom_id(Video.find(@video.id))%>').innerHTML = ("<%= j (render partial: 'book', locals: { book: @video }) %>")`

On the JS page `console.log('#<%=dom_id(Video.find(@video.id))%>')`
 gives me an output of `#video_12`

And on the view page `<% puts dom_id(Video.find(x.id)) %>` gives me an output of `video_12`

So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Any help is much appreciated.

Routes

```
resources :videos do#, only: [:index, :show] do
    member do
       put "upvote", to: "videos#upvote"
       put "downvote", to: "videos#downvote"
    end
end
```

_book.html.erb

```
<p> Title: <%= book.get_upvotes.size %> </p>
```

upvote.js.erb

```
Rails.$('.random-book')[1].innerHTML = ("<%= j (render partial: 'book', locals: { book: @video }) %>")
console.log('#<%=dom_id(Video.find(@video.id))%>')
console.log(Rails.$('.random-book')[0])
```

def upvote

```
def upvote
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @ip = request.remote_ip
    @was_it_upvoted = Ipaddresstracker.find_by(ipaddress: @ip, videoid: @video.id)
    if @was_it_upvoted
      @video.downvote_by User.first
      @was_it_upvoted.delete
    else
      Ipaddresstracker.create(:ipaddress => @ip, :videoid => @video.id)
      @video.vote_by voter: User.first, :duplicate => true
    end  
end
```

_index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<% @videos.each do |x| %>
<p> <div class="child">  
  <video controls width="310" height="230" src="<%= x.file %>"></video>
    <p> <%= x.title %> </p>

      <div>
        <%= link_to upvote_video_path(x), method: :put, remote: :true, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        Upvote
        <div class="random-book" id= <%= dom_id(Video.find(x.id)) %> > <%= x.get_upvotes.size %> </div>
  <% end %>
      <div>
        <br><br>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <p> Contributor: <%= x.contributor %> </p>
          <p> Email: <%= x.email %> </p>
          <p> Phone: <%= x.phone %> </p>
          <p> <%= link_to 'Destroy', x, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> </p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      </div>
</div> </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to add quotes

instead of

```
<div class="random-book" id= <%= dom_id(Video.find(x.id)) %> ></div>
```

do:

```
<div class="random-book" id="<%= dom_id(Video.find(x.id)) %>" ></div>
```

Comment: I had that thought too earlier, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Figured it out, just had to use straight Jquery instead of Javascript so my upvote.js.erb file looks like this now `$('#<%=dom_id(Video.find(@video.id))%>').html("<%= j (render partial: 'book', locals: { book: @video }) %>")`